# retrieve array two dimension php

Tags: php

i have create array two dimension like this and how i can retrive array two dimension

```
   stdClass Object
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [data] => Array`enter code here`
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nama_mahasiswa] => STANY SUMARNA
                    [jenis_kelamin] => L
                    [tanggal_lahir] => 1996-07-31                    
                    [nama_status_mahasiswa] => AKTIF
                    [nim] => 16304117
                    [id_periode] => 20161               
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nama_mahasiswa] => ADAM
                    [jenis_kelamin] => L
                    [tanggal_lahir] => 1996-07-31                    
                    [nama_status_mahasiswa] => AKTIF
                    [nim] => 16304117
                    [id_periode] => 20161               
                )
[2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nama_mahasiswa] => STANY SUMARNA
                    [jenis_kelamin] => L
                    [tanggal_lahir] => 1996-07-31                    
                    [nama_status_mahasiswa] => AKTIF
                    [nim] => 16304117
                    [id_periode] => 20161               
                )
)
```

Comment: That's an object containing an array of objects. Are you just trying to get the array from the object? Please clarify what it is your trying to do. Include your attempt (you have tried something I hope?) together with the expected output, your actual output and where you're stuck.

Comment: You have not a multidimensional array, but object which have an array (`data`) of objects.

Comment: cause i new in php programming thanks for addvice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code
lets say $array = main array

```
$error_code = $array->error_code;
foreach($array->data as $row){
    $nama_mahasiswa = $row->nama_mahasiswa;
    $jenis_kelamin = $row->jenis_kelamin;
}
```